# Redirecting URLS with Multiple Sub-Folders

Tags: php, .htaccess

My websites have pages with .htm extensions and 'real' files like about.htm. 
So a URL to a page always has the format of http://www.whatever.com/about.htm.

This works well but the SEO guys want to be clever and make the URLS in the format: http://www.whatever.com/cool-website/awesome-content/about.htm.

I have figured out in PHP how to cut up a URL and thus find the right page in the database.

So, what I am trying to do is get ALL requests redirected to ROOT/index.php and then in there 'cut up' the URL to find the .htm needed and thus serve the right page.

I have got this to work if there are no sub-folders.
However, as soon as the URL has sub-folders like '/cool-website/awesome-content/' I just get 404 error.

I think I need an HTACCESS entry of some sort, but have tried loads but no joy.

Really appreciate some advice here.
Thanks

Comment: **I have got this to work if there are no sub-folders.** Can you show how you got this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most PHP frameworks tell you how to do this, it's referred to as a front controller.

Take a look at the top of [this Zend Framework doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html); it explains what you need to put into a `.htaccess` folder at the root of the project.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$ index.php
```

OR (Preferred)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

From there you can do the slicing and dicing you want in `index.php`.

Comment: Thanks for this HTACCESS, which works really well at root level. I want to test this on a test site that sits in /1test/ folder. So the url of the test site root would be http://www.whatever.com/1test . How do I tweak the HTACCESS in the Test Site Root folder?

Comment: Just drop the `.htaccess` file and corresponding `index.php` file into the `1test` directory. Then when you navigate to `1test`, the `1test/.htaccess` file will trigger `1test/index.php` file.

Comment: Excellent Quickshiftin - works a treat - Thanks for your help!